# Method of acyclic models and Eilenberg-Zilber theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently reading Spanier's AT.

> Theorem (Eilenberg-Zilber theorem) On the category of ordered pairs of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, there is a natural chain equivalence of the functor $\Delta(X\times Y)$ with the functor $\Delta(X)\otimes \Delta(Y)$.

Proof outline: Both functors are free and acyclic with models $\{\Delta^p,\Delta^q\}_{p,q\geq 0}$. Then by the method of acyclic models, the statement follows.

So far, my understanding the method of acyclic model is the following

> Theorem. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with models $\mathfrak{M}$ and let $G$ and $G'$ be covariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to the category of chain complexes such that $G$ is free and nonnegative and $G'$ is acyclic in positive dimensions. Then
> $(a)$ Any natural transformation $H_0(G)\to H_0(G')$ is induced by a natural chain map $\tau:G\to G'$ $(b)$ Two natural chain maps $\tau,\tau':G\to G'$ inducing the same natural transformation $H_0(G)\to H_0(G')$ are naturally chain homotopic.

I think the proof uses $(b)$ of the statement. But how do we know the 'in positive dimension' condition satisfied? I think once it's clear then everything is fine.

Comment: This might help: https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/some-applications-of-acyclic-models-in-algebraic-topology/ and https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/the-method-of-acyclic-models/

Comment: Spanier **proves** that both functors are acyclic in positive dimensions. You should explain if you need help to undestand his proof or if you have some other problem.

Comment: @PaulFrost I can't see where he prove the positive dimension condition. Spanier only proves both functors are free and acyclic with models $\{\Delta^p,\Delta^q\}_{p,q\geq 0}$

Comment: Spanier proves that the *reduced chain complexes* associated to $\Delta(X\times Y)$ and $\Delta(X)\otimes \Delta(Y)$ are acyclic. This is the same as the acyclicity of the unreduced complexes in positive dimensions. See p. 168.

Comment: @PaulFrost Oh, right. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should write an answer to your own question?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think comment is enough.